# Is it possible to run a Vagrant box inside an Ubuntu Virtual box machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I currently have a windows 10 which I like for everything, except when it comes to development. So whenever I need to work, I run an Ubuntu virtual box machine and I code there.

I recently started working with a team that uses Vagrant boxes (For development environments) and Ansible (For provisioning). My question is, **is it possible to run a Vagrant box inside my Ubuntu virtual machine to provision it with Ansible?** (Since it is only available on Linux distros).

I realize that this is a bit confusing since I am running a virtual machine inside another. Is there any way I can go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant is able to run on windows, you can set a nice directory sharing and you can access that directory from your other VM. If provision is part of the Vagrantfile, you don't have to worry whether this will work in windows or not because most of the provisioners run inside the created machine already.

For Ansible, you should use [Ansible Local](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html) provisioner. That will let it run on guest machine completely and you won't need Ansible on the host machine.

Comment: But how would I install Ansible on this box from inside the box even if I use file sharing?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize Ansible is a special case, I will update my answer.